# Lost metadata on Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, metadata, time-series

I'm working with time series data and am trying to qualify operations on various time series based on the original sampling frequency (or other relevant metadata) of that time series. I can successfully set the metadata with the following:

```
a_df._metadata = ["orig_freq"]
a_df["a_col"].orig_freq = "D"
```

This appears to be successful. Now I want to apply functions based on metadata criteria:

```
for i in a_df.columns:
    if a_df[i].orig_freq == "D":
        a_df[i + "_a_new_col"] = a_function(a_df[i])
    else:
        a_df[i + "_a_new_col"] = a_function_2(a_df[i])
```

This works for the first column in the dataframe, but after successfully operating on that column, I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'orig_freq'
```

At this point, all of the assigned metadata has been deleted. Am I doing something wrong in the metadata assignment?

Comment: shouldn't it be `i.orig_freq` ?

Comment: The metadata should be specific to each column, which represents a distinct time series. The entire dataframe has been standardized to a single sampling frequency, but I want to retain the information of the individual original sampling frequency for each included column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `_metadata` needs to be defined on the class (ie. `Series._metadata`), although even then,  there may be some issues.  E.g., see this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6923) for more discussion.

If each column has one piece of metadata, your life might be easier just using `MultiIndex` columns to store it.  Eg, something like this:

```
In [43]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

In [44]: orig_freqs = {'a': 'D', 'b': 'Q'}

In [45]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(([(c, orig_freqs[c]) for c in df]))

In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
   a  b
   D  Q
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [47]: for (col, orig_freq) in df:
    ...:     df[('new_col', orig_freq)] = a_function(df[(col, orig_freq)])
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Yes, I would imagine that defining metadata for the class would be problematic.